# Field update on related object based on case closed

Tags: apex, trigger

"Account" has a Case related through a look field on Account. When Case is "closed" then update **CaseClosed**(i.e., I created a Check box field in Account) Checkbox field = true in Account.

```
trigger  setCaseClosedCheckboxAccount on Case (after update,after insert,before update,before insert) {

    Map<Id,Id>  AccountToCaseMap = new Map<Id,Id>();

    for(Case c : trigger.new)

        AccountToCaseMap.put(c.AccountId,c.Id);

    List<Account> AccountUpdate = new List<Account>{};

    for (Account acc: [SELECT Id,Name, CaseClosed__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN:  AccountToCaseMap.keySet()]) {
        Id caId = AccountToCaseMap.get(acc.Id);
        Case ca = trigger.newMap.get(caId);
        if (ca.Status=='Closed' ){
            acc.CaseClosed__c=true;
            AccountUpdate.add(acc);
        }

        else if (ca.Status=='Closed' && ca.Status!=null ){
            acc.CaseClosed__c =true;
            AccountUpdate.add(acc);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if I have the right approach. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you having a specific problem?

Comment: My above trigger code is not working properly, what i am doing mistake on above code.

Comment: Please, take a second and check out the [ask] article. And then please edit your question and tell us what errors you're having, how the application is behaving, if there are any messages (and stack trace if possible). It will be really tough to help you without that. :)

Comment: Why are you not sure whether you're on the right approach ? IT's always a good idea to tell us information exactly rather than vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two major issues:

1. Trigger is running on all events which is unnecessary.
2. You need to perform `update` DML as you are updating different object on which trigger is running.

It should be like:

```
trigger setCaseClosedCheckboxAccount on Case (after update) 
{

    Map<Id,Id>  AccountToCaseMap = new Map<Id,Id>();

    // Check for correct event
    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate)
        for(Case c : trigger.new)
            AccountToCaseMap.put(c.AccountId,c.Id);

    List<Account> AccountUpdate = new List<Account>{};

    for (Account acc: [SELECT Id,Name, CaseClosed__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN:  AccountToCaseMap.keySet()]) 
    {
        Id caId = AccountToCaseMap.get(acc.Id);
        Case ca = trigger.newMap.get(caId);
        if (ca.Status=='Closed' )
        {
            acc.CaseClosed__c=true;
            AccountUpdate.add(acc);
        }

        else if (ca.Status=='Closed' && ca.Status!=null )
        {
            acc.CaseClosed__c =true;
            AccountUpdate.add(acc);
        }
    }

    // update records
    update AccountUpdate;
}
```

Follow best practices to write trigger. Follow the [link (Trigger Frameworks and Apex Trigger)](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices)

Comment: Error: Invalid Data.
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger setCaseClosedCheckboxAccount caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: setCaseClosedCheckboxAccount: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Trigger.setCaseClosedCheckboxAccount: line 13, column 1

Comment: @user28787 What is written on line 13?

Comment: Now code is working f9.. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Process Builder for your requirements instead of writing trigger.

1. Choose Object and Specify When to Start the Process

Choose Object as Case

2. Define Criteria for this Action Group

[image: Define Criteria]

3. Update Records

[image: Update Records]

Please let me know, if it is solving your purpose and vote for me.

Thanks,
Santanu

Answer (score 0):

Instead of updating the checkbox field using code, you can turn it into a formula field (checkbox) and write the logic in formula field.

Example: `Primary_Case__r.IsClosed`